# Android: unable to run shell script in my android app programmatically

Tags: java, android, shell, adb, android-shell

My script is located in the Download folder of the device and it's path is **/storage/emulated/0/Download/**

My shell script contains: **testSharath.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
#!/system/bib/sh

echo "Hello from testSharath.sh"
ps -e
```

I tried to execute above shell script in my android code:

```
private void testShellScript() {
        File testPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        String fileName = "testSharath.sh";
        File scriptFilePath = new File(testPath, fileName);
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/opt/homebrew/bin/adb shell chmod +x " +scriptFilePath);
            // Get the output stream of the process
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            String line;

            // Read and print each line of the output
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Sharath@@@@@@"+line);
            }
            // Close the reader
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Exception:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/opt/homebrew/bin/adb": error=2, No such file or directory

My path is correct

Comment: Are you sure that you have homebrew installed on your android device? That `/opt/homebrew/bin/adb` exists **on your android device**?

Comment: No, It's installed on my macbook, adb path which gives the same path so I used the same path /opt/homebrew/bin/adb, I don't know how to install in our android device!! any suggestion always welcome here.!!  @ThomasKläger

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
private void testShellScript() {
        try {

            String scriptFilePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/testSharath.sh";
    
            
            Process chmodProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod +x " + scriptFilePath);
            chmodProcess.waitFor();
    
            
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(scriptFilePath);
    
            
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    
            String line;
    
            
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Sharath@@@@@@" + line);
            }
    
            
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting below exception when I used your code:  java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/storage/emulated/0/Download/testSharath.sh": error=13, Permission denied
2023-11-13 12:18:29.227  9001-9055  System.err              com.lotus.sync.traveler              W  java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/storage/emulated/0/Download/testSharath.sh": error=13, Permission denied
2023-11-13 12:18:29.228  9001-9055  System.err              com.lotus.sync.traveler              W  Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied